# Is it a good practice to use a class C as the member of class B that is the member of class A? If not, how to decompose this situation?

Tags: design

I've a issue that hasn't been answered for long. Say, using a class C as the member of class B that is the member of class A (or even deeper nested). When I design some classes I often design such nested classed. I know that it often makes trouble, for example, if you forget to initialze a member of such class, the code will report null error. The code example is as follows:

```
public class Automobile {
      public DrivingSystem
      public ElectricSystem
      ....
};
public class DrivingSystem {
      public Wheel
      public Gear
      ....
};
public class Wheel {
      public Button
      public SteelRing
      ....
};
```

I think this is a widespread issue but I donot find any systematic discussion about it (when I search "Nested Class", it always comes out with inner class), So I have to post my **doubts** here: **Is it a good practice to use a class C(Wheel) as the member of class B(DrivingSystem) that is the member of class A(Automobile)?  If not, how to decompose this situation?**  I appreciate if anyone could solve this issue.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner the classes are of course depended just as you described. For example, I've a class Car, it has a property: Class DrivingSystem, and in DrivingSystem, it has a property: Class Wheel..... Is it Ok to put them nested as I described?

Comment: I deleted my initial comment since I was unsure whether I understood your question correctly (and the non-descript names didn't help to understand better). It might help if you use meaningful names in your example. What you have are not nested classes, but properties having some class as types. That is pretty normal composition, and as long as you don't overcomplicate it it's fine.

Comment: I have trouble to understand this (pseudo?) code. For example, is `i` indented to be a property of type `B`? Or does A contain a member of type B plus a property i? Or is A derived from B? Or can you rewrite the code in a more common syntax?

Comment: .... but trying to give you some feedback on the general idea of using attributes of one class inside another - this is definitely ok - larger programs and data structures will  usually be composed of smaller building bricks in a hierarchical manner, that's the whole idea of structural [decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_(computer_science))

Comment: @DocBrown hi, property i is just another property of Class A, no relation with B. Sorry for my psuedo code.

Comment: @DocBrown as my personal experience, if class is nested as a property, it must be initialized in its composing class's constructor. But I often forgot doing this, for example, I forgot to write the initialization of class C and when I created class A , class C is actually a null, and that often leads to a disaster. I was wondering if there's any good way to avoid it.

Comment: The nesting is not bad in itself (but I'd avoid creating very long chains). The problem is more along the lines of: Suppose function F uses an instance of your class A to do something - if you then change something fairly inconsequential about class C, does it also affect your function F (or indeed, all the other classes up the chain). If so, then you've created a tower of cards (collapses easily). The "Tell Don't Ask" principle and the so called "Law of Demeter" are a kind of guideline to help you address this. The idea is to express the logic at a single level of abstraction at each level.

Comment: @all Sorry, I just found that my psuedo code contradicts with my description. I just changed it so everyone understand it clear.

Comment: *"I forgot to write the initialization of class C and when I created class A , class C is actually a null,"* - use a programming language environment where the compiler warns you when you forget to initialize a member variable. Problem solved. And what you wrote will become a lot more understandable when you start to distinguish clearly between classes and variables or properties of a certain type.

Answer (score 3):

This is how object-oriented programming works at a base level; objects are composed of other objects. Sometimes those objects are native types (`int`, `string`, etc) and sometimes they are our own types (`Car`, `DrivingSystem`, `Wheel`, etc).

Indeed, as the systems get larger and more complex, there will be many, many instances of these kinds of properties. And, in many cases, a class will have more than one such property.

```csharp
public class Car {
    public Engine EngineSystem;
    public DriveTrain DrivingSystem;
    public Dashboard Dash;
    ...etc
}

public class Engine {
    public Energy Fuel;
    ...etc
}

public class Energy {
    public double Amount;
    public string Type;
}

public class Dashboard {
    public Radio RadioSystem;
    public IntrumentPanel Instruments;
    ...etc
}
```

Your concern with this seems to stem from making sure everything is properly initialized:

> I know that it often makes trouble, for example, if you forget to initialize a member of such class, the code will report null error.

There are patterns to deal with initializing and constructing objects (the [Factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), to name a couple). The simplest might be to just provide a default constructor with appropriate values. This isn't always possible, though (what's on a default `Dashboard`, after all).

There is some discipline required to make sure you are initializing all of the required objects, even with one of those patterns (you still have to call some variation of `Dash = new Dashboard();` when creating a `Car`, after all). Code stylers, code analyzers, IDEs, and the like can virtually eliminate the problem of uninitialized objects, as many of them (at least in my experience with C#) will flag a potentially uninitialized property just like it would a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I've studied the design patterns before, but when it comes to actual coding,  these design pattern principles are least noticed and implemented. (I could use polymorphism, though, but to a further step seems be rare).

Answer (score 1):

This is called [object composition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) and is at the hart of OOP. So there is nothing wrong here. By the way, these classes are not nested.

Two important remarks however:

- the more problematic design, is when at the top class, e.g. `Automobile`, you make assumptions about the included class downwards, and start to work directly with the public `Wheel`. This would create a coupling  that is often undesired in view  of the [principle of least knowledge](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).
- when your design requires to work frequently across the composition hierarchy, it can get borring with a lot of boilerplate code. In this case you could consider the [composite design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/composite) or one of its many patterns.

Comment: Could you explain the first remark? thanks

Comment: @Lake_Lagunita I made it because it was not clear in your code snippet how you use the composition. Classes should help to separate concerns and hide the implementation. i.e. you could decide to implement DrivingSystem differently, e.g 3 wheels instead of 4, or some or in a distant futur perhaps caterpillars instead of wheels. If your Automobile make assumptions about how the DrivingSystem works, it is fully dependent of it and any change in the implementation of the DrivingSystem would require to change as well the Automobile. You can avoid this with the "Tell don't ask" principle.

Comment: Sorry what I mean by wheel is driving wheel. Forgive my erroneous use as a non-native speaker

Comment: @Lake_Lagunita no problem. I'm not sufficiently native speaker to have recognized the ambiguity. This doesn't change the reasoning, even now there are direction systems without a steering wheel (https://www.popsci.com/technology/zoox-robotaxi-carrying-people-public-roads/?amp or https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HQtGmyVaUu4 or many others). If your car assumes a steering wheel, you prevent innovative direction systems (i.e you prevent safe future evolution of your classes)

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with this exact approach is that in languages like C++ DrivingSystem containing a Wheel means you have an instance of Wheel, and cannot have a subclass of Wheel. So in C++ you might prefer an instance variable of type Wheel*.

Advantage: You can use a subclass of Wheel. Dubious advantage: You can have a null pointer. Disadvantage: You need to write source code to create or delete the Wheel.

About the nesting: The  Automobile class knows nothing about Wheel. It knows about DrivingSystem. How DrivingSystem works is an implementation detail. Automobile doesn’t know about the nested classes.